# Compile error when using Echo

Tags: go, package

I made a simple work using github.com/labstack/echo package while running I got this error.

> github.com\labstack\echo\echo.go:624: e.AutoTLSManager.HTTPHandler
>   undefined (type autocert.Manager has no field or method HTTPHandler

```
package main

import "github.com/labstack/echo"

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Start(":")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is addressed in [issue #1082](https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1082):

> You seem to have a stale acme/autocert library. autocert.Manager DOES currently have that method: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert#Manager.HTTPHandler I suggest a `go get -u golang.org/x/crypto/acme/...`.